# Storing multilingual content that is used across sections

Tags: localization

I'm new to Craft, but starting off with building a multilingual site. I wonder what is best practice for storing multilingual content that is used accross sections (i.e. site navigation headings, footer link text). I know about the static translation files, but I want to enable local editors to translate those themselves in the CP.

Answer (score 5):

I am fairly new to Craft myself but I think the best approach for that type of content would be to set up [Globals](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/globals) I think you can then make them translatable and common translations can be added to in a [translations file](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager/tree/master/final/web/craft/translations). Have a look at the [HappyLager](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager/tree/master/final) site to see how that works. I have found it really useful.

Comment: I agree, Globals is your best solution for this.

Comment: Hi @Genoil could you mark this as the answer if you are happy with it please?